# TLS handshake over websockets

Tags: ssl, websocket, handshake

I've set out to handle tls operations manually on a websockets server, due to the cockeyed way php supports listening on secured transports.From RFC6455:

> If /secure/ is true, the client MUST perform a TLS handshake over the
>   connection after opening the connection and before sending the
>   handshake data [RFC2818].  If this fails (e.g., the server's
>   certificate could not be verified), then the client MUST *Fail the
>   WebSocket Connection* and abort the connection.  Otherwise, all
>   further communication on this channel MUST run through the encrypted
>   tunnel [RFC5246].

According to this, the first thing I should receive is the clientHello message which signifies the beginning of a TLS handshake.But all I receive on the server is the websocket handshake request, encrypted.
I am baffled by this.Is there no TLS handshake at all?

Comment: It works the same than HTTPS, can you see the clientHello message if you start a HTTPS connection with your browser to whenever are you listening?

Comment: I am receiving data in some form of encoding, just like what I supposed was the websocket header request.I always assumed the tls handshake would be in plain text, but it's clear it needs some parsing...Thanks for the tip, the page dies with an "SSL error" message.

Comment: There are great illustrations here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake